# How do I style an option in a select that is both disabled and selected?

Tags: javascript, css, html-select

I want some options to be shown in red, and not to be selectable by the user on the form. These options can be selected via JS. I want these disabled options to appear red in both the drop-down list (actually it would be better if they weren't visible at all in the drop-down list) and, if selected, in the field when the user has not clicked on it. My current solution shows the options in red in the drop-down list, but do NOT appear in red in the field if selected.

Here's the code:

```js
function do_it() {
  var tickselect = document.getElementById('TB_038_116');
  var tickvalue = tickselect.options[tickselect.selectedIndex].value;
  if (tickvalue == 0) {
    tickselect.value = 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <center>Styling Disabled Selected Options</center>
</h1>
<select id='TB_038_116' class='tickbox'>
<option value='0' disabled selected>Option 0</option>
<option value='1'>Option 1</option>
<option value='2'>Option 2</option>
<option value='3'>Option3</option>
<option value='4' style='color: red;' disabled>Option 4</option>
<option value='5' style='color: red;' disabled>Option 5</option>
</select>
<button type='button' onclick='do_it()'>Click Me</button>
```

I need the option 4 to appear in red after clicking the button.

Can I separately style the option in the drop-down list and in the control when not clicked? This would be a cumbersome solution, because the style needs to be different for options 4 and 5 than for options 1, 2, and 3, so I'd have to change the style dynamically every time the selected option changed.

Can I style an option that is selected and disabled?

Comment: Disabled options can't be selected. That's what disabled *means*. It's unclear what you're asking for here.

Comment: Yes, they can, as my snippet clearly shows. By JS.

Answer (score 0):

when you click the button then it is selecting the option 4 that is why it's display gray and its working fine in firefox

```js
function do_it() {
    var tickselect = document.getElementById('TB_038_116');
    var tickvalue = tickselect.options[tickselect.selectedIndex].value;
    if (tickvalue == 0) {
   tickselect.value = 4;
   tickselect.className='redText';
    }
  }
```

```css
.tickbox{ color:black; }
.redText{ color:red; }
option:disabled {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container body-content">
    <h1>
    <center>Styling Disabled Selected Options</center>
  </h1>
  <select id='TB_038_116' class='tickbox' >
  <option value='0' disabled="disabled" selected>Option 0</option>
  <option value='1' class='tickbox'>Option 1</option>
  <option value='2' class='tickbox'>Option 2</option>
  <option value='3' class='tickbox'>Option 3</option>
  <option value='4' style='color: red;' class='redText' disabled>Option 4</option>
  <option value='5' style='color: red;' class='redText' disabled>Option 5</option>
  </select>
  <button type='button' onclick='do_it()'>Click Me</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's getting closer. But now ALL the options appear red once they are selected, having clicked the button. This is not what I want/need. I need options 4 and 5 to show in red, and options 1, 2 and 3 to show in black. I suppose I could do this by having an event fire whenever anyone changes the selected option (how do I do this?) and change the colour, but this seems an awful lot of trouble. Is there a better way?

Comment: I just tried to do this, by adding an onchange event. It didn't work. Here's the code:

Answer (score 0):

After much reading, searching and absorbing help from this forum and others, I have come up with something that works:

```js
function setcolour(pos) {
 pos.className = pos[pos.selectedIndex].className;
 pos.blur();
}

function sel_opt(option) {
 var tickselect = document.getElementById('TB_038_116');
 var tickvalue = tickselect.options[tickselect.selectedIndex].value;
 if (tickvalue == 0) {
 tickselect.value = option;
 setcolour(tickselect);
 }
}
```

```css
select, option {
 color: black; 
}

select.redtick {
 color: red; 
}

select.blacktick { 
 color: black; 
}

option.redtick {
 color: red; 
 display: none;
}

option.blacktick { 
 color: black; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><center>Styling Disabled Selected Options</center></h1>
<select id='TB_038_116' class='tickbox' onchange="setcolour(this)">
<option class='blacktick' style='display: none;' value='0' disabled selected>Option 0</option>
<option class='blacktick' value='1'>Option 1</option>
<option class='blacktick' value='2'>Option 2</option>
<option class='blacktick' value='3'>Option 3</option>
<option class='redtick' value='4' disabled>Option 4</option>
<option class='redtick' value='5' disabled>Option 5</option>
</select>
<button type='button' onclick='sel_opt(4)'>Select Option 4</button>
<button type='button' onclick='sel_opt(5)'>Select Option 5</button>
```

The key issues seem to be:

1. Options of a select are displayed in two ways, (a) in the drop-down list of options when you click the select, and (b) once selected, in the select itself.
2. The styling of the option determines the style of the option when displayed in method (a). It does **not** affect the style of the option when displayed in method (b), which is entirely determined by the style of the select.
3. There is no way in CSS to set the style of an individual option when displayed in method (b). Therefore it is necessary to change the style of the select programmatically every time the selected option is changed.
4. The jQuery function in my example does this when the options are changed manually by the user, using an onchange event, copying the style from the selected option to the select.
5. The onchange event is **not** fired by programmatic changes, therefore the Javascript that makes the change has to call the function explicitly.

We got there in the end! Thanks to everyone who helped me understand this and get to a solution.

Rowan

Comment: After posting this, my account has been blocked from adding more questions. What have I done wrong? The rules of this site seem so obscure and difficult to comply with as to make the site pretty well useless.